# Can't Go Back in File Tree with ../

Tags: python, html, css, postgresql, flask

I have a file structure like this for my website

```
css
  style.css
  other files...
templates
  index.html
  other files...
```

and I am trying to refer to style.css from my index.html file.

I've tried to go back a directory with ../

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
```

but it's giving me a 404 error. I have tried to refer to other files in different directories using the same method, but that doesn't work either. Any ideas?

P.S. Not sure this matters, but this is a Python application using the Flask framework and PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it's a Flask application actually matters quite a bit. If this were something like vanilla PHP, your html page would be served up at `yoursite.com/templates/index.html`. Because it's Flask, you're probably serving it at `yoursite.com/index` (or whatever other path you've decided).

Your relative reference to the css path is actually trying to go a level above the root domain. If you changed the reference to the below and set up a path to serve that file at that route, it would work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

But that would be a lot of effort. Instead, you should be using Flask's [built in url_for()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/templates/) and /static folder structure (instead of /css)

```
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
```